# How to convert row values of a column to columns - JDBCTemplate and PostgreSQL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I currently have a table:

```
id | info  | value       | date 
1  | desc  | description | 19-01-1990 10:01:23
2  | lname | Doe         | 19-11-1990 10:01:23
1  | fname | John        | 19-08-1990 10:01:23
1  | dob   | dob         | 19-05-1990 10:01:23
3  | fname | Jo          | 19-01-1990 10:01:23
```

I would like to query and grab data and do joins with multiple tables later on, so I need it to be:

```
id | desc        | lname | fname | dob | desc        | date        | ... |
1  | description | Doe   | John  | dob | description | 19-01-1990 10:01:23 | ... |
2  | .........   | ..... | Jo    |     |             | ...         | ... |
```

I have tried crosstab but it does not seem to work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should include the full expected output based on the sample input data.  In particular, you should show us exactly what that `date` column is going to look like.

Comment: You haven't answered my question.  Please include the values for the `date` column in your output.

Comment: So you want the earliest date for each `id` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am hoping to get the info column values e.g. desc, lname, fname as columns and so a row is for an id

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was not clear but I am trying to transpose my rows into columns based on id as the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current table is a typical denormalized key value store.  You may generate the normalized output you want by aggregating by `id` and then using max `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN info = 'desc'  THEN value END) AS desc,
    MAX(CASE WHEN info = 'lname' THEN value END) AS lname,
    MAX(CASE WHEN info = 'fname' THEN value END) AS fname,
    MAX(CASE WHEN info = 'dob'   THEN value END) AS dob
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    id
ORDER BY
    id;
```

Note that I don't have any column for the date, as you did not give logic for *which* date value should be retained for each `id`.

As for the Spring part of your question, you would probably have to use a native query to execute the above.